# BadTokenException at AutoCompleteTextView showDropDown() inside a listener

Tags: android

I have two activities, activity1 is starting activity2.
in activity 2 I registered an OnFocusChangeListener to a AutoCompleteTextView:

```
someTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus)
    ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).showDropDown();
    else
    ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).dismissDropDown();
}       
});
```

if i write something in the textview and then the activity configuration changes (screen rotate) I get the WindowManager.BadTokenException.
I isolated this to the showDropDown and dismissDropdown methods (by commenting them).
I also tried executing those two methods directly on the Activity's View object (instead of the one passed through the listener) and got the same exception.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are aware that when the screen rotates, that *by default* your existing activity is destroyed and a new one created to replace it?

Comment: yes, but I still don't understand what is wrong with what I'm trying to do. I'm pretty new to Android development..

Comment: can you please explain what is the problem with this code? on configuration change the activity is destroyed and a new one is created, then a new activity is created and a new listener is regsitered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the orientations change the atctivity destory and create again. By this the open list of auto-complete which was create by context of previous activity context will destory as activity is destory. You have to handle orientiaon change your self. So that on rotation activity not destory and auto-complete list view remain same.

Please add This line on your in you AndroidManifest.xml in activity tag.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

e.g

```
<activity
            android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation = "sensor"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Comment: it's a textview and not an open dialog

Comment: it works, thanks! do I need to actually take care of anything regarding rotation now, for example inflating the correct layout ?

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark answer as accepted. No other thing are fine. as only view re-draw itself.

Comment: i read that google doesn't recommend handling orientation changes. is there another way to do what I'm trying to do in that code ?

Comment: Check this android link. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: according to the android documents objects which are related to activities can't be retained and they strongly suggest against handling the configuration change (which also doesn't take advantage of multiple resources), 
is there a way to do what I'm trying to do in the original question without handling orientation change on my own ?

Comment: what happens if the activity is in the background and destroyed by the system, will the user get an exception ?

Comment: I posted a follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037364/explanation-about-activity-re-creation-on-configuration-change-and-context

Comment: Well if you know what you are doing its safe enough to handle orientation changes. Look at the YouTube app - it does it when rotating the screen. Then the same player view is expanded to take up the entire screen.
Had this been handled by the device there would have been a pause and the stream would have to restart from last stored point.