# explanation about activity re-creation on configuration change and context

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android development and I'm looking for explanation about a problem I'm facing, for gaining deeper understanding of Android.

I have this piece of code:

```
someAutoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).showDropDown();
        else
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).dismissDropDown();
    }       
});
```

if the dropdown list is visible and the configuration changes (screen orientation) I'm getting a BadTokenException.

I understand that the activity is destroyed and a new one is created to replace it, but I don't quite understand what's really going on and why am I getting that exception,
after all, a new activity is created with new listeners registered to the new views and the old ones are destroyed.

I know that I can fix this by telling the manifest that I'll be handling configuration changes by myself, but I'm looking into deeper understanding.

thanks!

Comment: Please share your full code and also the full logcat.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose that when you are in landscape mode, and when the AutoCompleteTextView is focused, this editable field is switching to "Full Screen Mode", i.e. only the value and the keyboard are shown on screen.

So I guess in this case the drop down is never visible and that is why showDropDown() throws an exception.

To avoid this, add the following lines in your code:

```
someAutoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if (v.getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            return;
        }

        if (hasFocus)
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).showDropDown();
        else
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).dismissDropDown();
    }       
});
```

Comment: This solved my problem which was very similar (but in a sub-class of AutoCompleteTextView)